# Sorting/Creating nested arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

This is the code that I have so far, although the size of the array needs to change. I need to add values to the array using a loop; to do this, I think I need to use a nested ArrayList. However, would I be able to sort the ArrayList in the same way as I have already done below, or is there a way in which I can add to this array?

```java
 public static void main(final String[] args) {

     String[][] data = new String[][] {
            new String[] { "Roy","3", "12" },
            new String[] { "Daniel","5", "22" },
            new String[] { "Joe","2", "3" },
            new String[] { "Ryan","4", "4" },
            new String[] { "Leroy","2", "5" },
            new String[] { "Smith","1", "6" },};



    Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
             String st1 = entry1[2];
             String st2 = entry2[2];
             int n1 = Integer.parseInt(st1);
             int n2 = Integer.parseInt(st2);
             return Integer.compare(n2, n1);

        }
    });




    for ( String[] s : data) {
        System.out.println(s[0] + "            " + s[1]+ "           " + s[2]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Declare `data` as `List<String[]>` (or `ArrayList<String[]>`) and use `Collections.sort` for sorting. You can even use the same Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, doesn't seem to be a problem. Instead of `String[][]` (an array of string arrays), change the type of `data` to `Arraylist<String[]>` (an array*list* or string arrays). So that would look like:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

     ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
     data.add(new String[] { "Roy","3", "12" });
     data.add(new String[] { "Daniel","5", "22" });
     data.add(new String[] { "Joe","2", "3" });
     data.add(new String[] { "Ryan","4", "4" });
     data.add(new String[] { "Leroy","2", "5" });
     data.add(new String[] { "Smith","1", "6" });

     Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
             String st1 = entry1[2];
             String st2 = entry2[2];
             int n1 = Integer.parseInt(st1);
             int n2 = Integer.parseInt(st2);
             return Integer.compare(n2, n1);
        }
    });

    //Other stuff...
}
```

Perhaps you meant you want the inner string arrays to be dynamically sizable. This is no problem either, and it nests exactly as you think it would.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

     String[][] rawData = new String[][] {
        new String[] { "Roy","3", "12" },
        new String[] { "Daniel","5", "22" },
        new String[] { "Joe","2", "3" },
        new String[] { "Ryan","4", "4" },
        new String[] { "Leroy","2", "5" },
        new String[] { "Smith","1", "6" }};

     ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
     for(String[] arr : rawData){
         ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
         data.add(a);
         for(String s : arr){
             a.add(s);
         }
     }

     Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ArrayList<String> entry1, ArrayList<String> entry2) {
             String st1 = entry1.get(2);
             String st2 = entry2.get(2);
             int n1 = Integer.parseInt(st1);
             int n2 = Integer.parseInt(st2);
             return Integer.compare(n2, n1);
        }
    });

    //Other stuff...
}
```

In both cases, you should be careful about your comparator accessing index `2`. What happens if the array (or arraylist) is only of length 1? What do you want the comparator to do in that case? And they are lists of strings which are hopefully integers but may not be. What do you want the comparator to do if it's trying to compare 12 to "hello"?